# Team Services: Can't create a bug

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have the annoying problem in Visual Studio Team Services (online) that anytime I want to add a bug under a user story I can only select "Task" and not "Bug" anymore. This worked in the past.

I instantly get the following screen, without having the option to choose for task or bug:
http://s33.postimg.org/dgnwef1kv/task.png

Anyone that could help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click "Configure setting..." button and switch to "Working with bugs" tab. Select "Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with tasks." option.
[image]

Comment: many Thanks! I passed that screen a dozen of times and still miss the impact it could have! THank you